# R Download.File Issue with Excel Workbook

Tags: r, excel, download

I'm trying to download an Excel workbook using R's [download.file](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/utils/html/download.file.html) function.

When I download the file manually (using Internet Explorer or Chrome, right click & save as) then the file downloads and I can then open it in Excel without any problems.

When I use download.file in R, the file downloads and reports the correct file size. However when I then try to open the downloaded xls file in Excel 2010 I get the following error message:

> Excel found unreadable content in 'test.xls'. Do you want to recover the contents of this workbook? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes.

When I click Yes, nothing happens.

I've also tried accessing the file directly using the R package [xlsx](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xlsx/index.html), this also fails.

Comment: Did you try to download it in binary mode, by adding `mode="wb"` to `download.file` ?

Comment: I didn't but I have now and it works! If you put your comment down as an answer I'll accept.

Comment: Nice that it works. I just added an answer.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can try to download your file in binary mode (default for `download.file` is ASCII mode) with the `mode` argument. Something like :

```
download.file(myurl, mydestfile, mode="wb")
```