# R: Downloading an Excel file using a download link

Tags: html, r, excel, web-scraping

I am trying to retrieve an Excel file from the internet, but the link is a download link which automatically downloads the file. I have tried to read this directly into R, but it seems to corrupt the file, and make it unreadable.

I have tried:

```
  temp <- tempfile()
  download.file("https://animaldrugsatfda.fda.gov/adafda/app/search/public/ingredientsInformationExcel/Section2ActiveIngredients",temp)
  FDAAnimalApprovedDrugs <- readLines(temp)
```

Comment: Try `gdata::read.xls(temp)` for example

Comment: and/or ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099243/read-an-excel-file-directly-from-a-r-script

Comment: If the file is an xls file,  you cannot read it with `readLines`.  It does not contain text. Can you open the saved file with MS Excel?

Comment: The temp file? No. I cannot.

Comment: Just to clarify, if you look at the link, it's not a direct link to the spreadsheet where xls is in the address. Otherwise it would be easy.

Comment: @squishy ; this downloaded and read in without problem for me using either `gdata::read.xls(temp)` or  `readxl::read_xls(temp)`, and code / link from your question. If you are on Windows perhaps perhaps you need [mode="wb"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15250257/r-download-file-issue-with-excel-workbook)

Comment: thanks - the mode="wb" worked.